# Need help with start mining(I am getting like this)

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp, golang

I am new to ethereum private blockchain

System information:
 geth version:1.8.2 os&version:linux

synopsis: when i tried to connect peers to my private blockchain it showing like

```
WARN [03-20|11:41:32] Node data write error err="state node c56d5a…f2fb4a failed with all peers (1 tries, 1 peers)"
```

node is not at all syncing . i am running this since from a week please help me out

Steps to reproduce the behaviour:

```
         1.created two nodes using the geth 
         2.join them using admin.addPeer()
         3.peer is connected.                                                   Same error getting in node system and getting also  peer system.          I got this problem since last week.
```

Comment: In the future you should format your post. All the lines you posted were duplicates of each other, and without formatting it is near impossible to read. How are your two nodes connected? Are they on a LAN, WAN?

Comment: connected to LAN only

Comment: I connected using this command                           geth --port 30302 --networkid 58342 --rpc --rpcport 8745 --rpcaddr 10.0.0.5 --rpccorsdomain "*" console

Comment: when I use eth.syncing command it showing like this              eth.syncing
{
  currentBlock: 498287,
  highestBlock: 1459478,
  knownStates: 248675,
  pulledStates: 248675,
  startingBlock: 498287
}

Answer (score 0):

In order to start mining on a private blockchain you need to do a few things:

- create a genesis block
- init a geth node with genesis block
- start nodes to use the genesis block info
- start mining

---

#### Create a genesis block

Create a **genesis.json** file like this one

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 1234,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "1",
    "gasLimit": "1000000",
    "alloc": {}
}
```

And save it to `/tmp/genesis.json`

#### Init a geth node with genesis block

Create a directory for your node data for example

```
mkdir /tmp/node1
```

Enter that directory and init the chain status using the **genesis.json** you created above

```
$ geth --datadir=./ init /tmp/genesis.json
```

You should see `Successfully wrote genesis state`

#### Start nodes to use the genesis block info

Now you can start your server and start mining. In the same `/tmp/node1` directory run

```
$ geth --datadir=./ --networkid 1234 console
```

It will start your geth server and open a console for you. Make sure to match the `networkid` with the one in the **genesis.json** file and that you initialized the `/tmp/node1/` with the genesis block.

---

#### Start mining

Next you need to create an account, set it to be the account that receives the mined ether, and start mining.

Type these commands in the geth console

```
> personal.newAccount()
> miner.setEtherbase(eth.accounts[0])
> miner.start(1)
```

And it should start mining

Comment: The commands you wrote in **Start mining**, where do I execute them?

Comment: When you start `geth` with the `console` parameter there's a console where you can enter commands. You need to execute them there